# Batch File Adding Date To Filename

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a batch file 2 years ago that seemed to work great making a backup copy of an excel spreadsheet daily.  All of a sudden 1 day it stopped working properly and began assigning the variables literally instead of pulling the actual date so it just began overwriting itself every day.

I went from getting this file name: 
Tasty Schedule 2018 - 04-30-2018

To now getting this filename:
Tasty Schedule 2018 - ~4,2-~6,2-~0,4

Looking at the code it seems obvious where the values are coming from but I am not sure why the date is no longer being pulled.  Im assuming there had to be some type of system update that changed something to cause this?  What is the best way to fix this?  Please see my current code below:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%MM%-%DD%-%YYYY%

copy "J:\TROY C\2018 Schedule\Tasty Schedule 2018.xlsx" "J:\Joe's Folder\ChocScheduleBackUps\Tasty Schedule 2018 - %stamp%.xlsx"
```

Comment: Did you change the system path variable recently?  This folder path should exist in the system path variable. `C:\windows\System32\Wbem`.

Answer (score 1):

Launch the following command in a command prompt:

```
wmic OS Get localdatetime
```

This should show the date, you can start from there.

Verify your locale settings: the mentioned `WMIC` command is locale dependent.

In order to make `WMIC` work, you need to see the following when you run `set PATH` in a command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip>set PATH
Path=...;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;...
```

(Do no modify `C:\Windows` directory, your computer will not work anymore)

Comment: ('wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.)  Maybe this is why it isnt returning the date correctly now?

Comment: Most probably, can you check if this file exists? `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe`. In case it does, check if this directory is present in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I went into Environment Variables and did not see WMIC listed under user or system variables.  I added wmic as the variable and the location as the value under both but still get the same not recognized message when I run it from CMD.  The strange thing is that this worked perfectly for awhile and just stopped working one day.

Comment: That's not the way to do it: you need to verify if the mentioned path is present in your PATH environment variable. It might be that it is written as `%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem`.

Comment: Im not sure im totally following.  Im supposed to be in System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables correct?  There was no Value listed using that location (C:\ or SystemRoot) that pointed towards the wbem folder at all.  I clicked new and added one with the variable of wmic but it didnt seem to help.  are you saying C:\Windows should be changed to SystemRoot and tried that way?

Comment: How to modify your environment variables/PATH: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by adding 'C:\Windows\System32\wbem\' to PATH so that WMIC worked and also adding 'C:\Windows\System32\' to PATH so FIND would work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `RoboCopy` instead:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "dStamp="
For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null') Do If Not Defined dStamp Set "dStamp=%%B-%%C-%%A"
If Defined dStamp Copy "J:\TROY C\2018 Schedule\Tasty Schedule 2018.xlsx" "J:\Joe's Folder\ChocScheduleBackUps\Tasty Schedule 2018 - %dStamp%.xlsx"
```